# Start online meeting automatically - Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-live-meeting

When you create an online meeting with Microsoft Graph, it only shows you a public url to access (and i dont find how to start the meeting if you are not the organizer).

**Is there any way to start the online meeting if the organizer is not there?** Like getting a private url, add permisions to other link or something, that would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please let us know what APIs are you using? Are you trying to do it programmatically?

Comment: Could you please let us know if you are still facing the issue?

Comment: I just have the option to do it with an admin account. In the configuration of "Microsoft Teams admin center" following the steps: Meetings --> Meeting policies --> Turn on the "Let anonymous people start a meeting" --> Add it to an account. But I dont see any option to do it with the Microsoft Graph API. Sorry for the late reply, If you have any idea, I'd appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming meeting participants are either guest users or users from other organization, so they are not able to start the meeting directly and meeting creator has to admit them in lobby after starting the meeting. Meeting creator can set who can bypass the lobby. Pass lobbybypasssettings parameter in Graph request -
[Update the lobbyBypassSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-update-the-lobbybypasssettings)

Comment: If meeting participants are from the organization, is it possible to let them start the event? If so, how?
I would like to let anyone start the online meeting, or at least designate a specific email who is able to start it.

Comment: Please check the below possible options for the same - 
1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/set-csteamsmeetingpolicy?view=skype-ps#-allowanonymoususerstostartmeeting, 2. https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/add-co-organizers-to-a-meeting-in-teams-0de2c31c-8207-47ff-ae2a-fc1792d466e2#:~:text=To%20add%20co-organizers%20to%20a%20meeting%2C%20make%20sure,Select%20Save%20at%20the%20bottom%20of%20your%20screen. 3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/meeting-policies-in-teams#let-anonymous-people-start-a-meeting